# C# Regex, how can I check that a regex group contains only digits

Tags: c#, .net, regex

I made the following regex pattern in C#:

```cs
Regex pattern = new Regex(@"(?<prefix>retour-)?(?<trackingNumber>\s*[0-9]+\s*)(?<postfix>-([0]|[1-9]{1,2}))?");
```

```
(?<prefix>retour-)?(?<trackingNumber>\s*[0-9]+\s*)(?<postfix>-([0]|[1-9]{1,2}))?
```

- This is what I want: Three groups.

  - The `prefix` group is `"retour-"` and if it occurs it is at the beginning.
  - The `trackingNumber` group is mandatory and should consist only of digits.
  - The `postfix` group is `"-"` followed only by digits, it is not mandatory.
- I want the `trackingNumber` group to be a success only if it contains numbers. The same goes for the `postfix`. In a similar question, the problem was solved by using regex anchors `(^, $)` but in my case I cannot use them because the `trackingNumber` group starts in the middle.

[For example](https://regex101.com/r/9EwcIE/1):

- `"1234ABC3456"` should not be a success
- `"retour-123456-12B"` should also not be a success

The problem is that the regex `(?<trackingNumber>\s*[0-9]+\s*)` will return a success even for a series that does not contain only digit numbers.

Comment: At the moment your regex group captures whitespace and numbers. Perhaps you want `\s*(?<trackingNumber>[0-9]+)\s*` so that the whitespace is outside the capture group? The capture group will then only capture digits.

Comment: @DiplomacyNotWar yes you are right, I can put the white space outside the capture group.

Comment: You've provided 2 examples of negative tests, but you haven't listed any positive test cases.

Comment: This regex works for me, with anchors too: `^(?<prefix>retour-)?\s*(?<trackingNumber>\d+)\s*(?<postfix>-(\d+))?$` - [see here](https://regex101.com/r/Fo1pvU/1) - so  `retour-123456-123`, `123456-123`, and `123456` matches but `retour-123456-12B` does not.

Comment: @Dai you can post this as answer. I see where I made a mistake when trying anchors. I put the $ before ?, and that is why it probably did not work.

Comment: @Devid Gladly done

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This pattern works for me:

```
^(?<prefix>retour-)?\s*(?<trackingNumber>\d+)\s*(?<postfix>-(\d+))?$
```

| Input | Result |
| --- | --- |
| `1234ABC3456` | No match |
| `retour-123456-12B` | No match |
| `retour-123456-123` | prefix: `"retour-"`, trackingNumber: `"123456"`, postFix: `"-123"` |
| `543210-999` | trackingNumber: `"543210"`, postFix: `"-999"` |
| `987654` | trackingNumber: `"987654"` |

https://regex101.com/r/Fo1pvU/1